# Typescript method overloading with one parameter of different type (non-primitive)

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading, optional-parameters

Ok, what I would like to do is simple. I want to overload a method so that it can take one parameter, which is of non-primitive type.

I understand I can't do it like this because TypeScript losts all types when compiled to JavaScript. If one of the parameters was primitive (e.g. string), I could do it (typeof myString == "string").

```
public doSomething(typeA: TypeA);
public doSomething(typeB: TypeB);
public doSomething(type: TypeA | TypeB) {
    if (typeof type == "TypeA") {
        ... // obviously I can't do that, Javascript got no types
        ... // typeof type === "object"
    }
    else if (typeof type == "TypeB") { //the same }
    else { //undefined }
}
```

What I thought up is this:

```
public doSomething(typeA?: TypeA, typeB?: TypeB) {
    if (typeA) { ... }
    else if (typeB) { ... }
    else { //undefined }
}
```

Then I have to call this way:

```
doSomething(typeA, undefined); //to call TypeA version
doSomething(undefined, typeB); //to call TypeB version
```

Is such a design acceptable or is it better to rather create two separate methods?

### **EDIT:**

This notation is probably better. You are forced (by IDE) to add the undefined when you're calling the method.

```
public doSomething(typeA: TypeA | undefined, typeB: TypeB | undefined) {
    if (typeA) { ... }
    else if (typeB) { ... }
    else { //undefined }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have functions that check whether a value is of a certain type, and typescript has the notion of [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
interface TypeA {
    x: string;
}
function isTypeA(value: any): value is TypeA {
    return Object.keys(value).length === 1 && typeof value.x === "string";
}

interface TypeB {
    y: number;
}
function isTypeB(value: any): value is TypeB {
    return Object.keys(value).length === 1 && typeof value.y === "number";
}

function doSomething(typeA: TypeA);
function doSomething(typeB: TypeB);
function doSomething(type: TypeA | TypeB) {
    if (isTypeA(type)) {
        console.log(type.x);
    } else {
        console.log(type.y);
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20TypeA%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20isTypeA(value%3A%20any)%3A%20value%20is%20TypeA%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(value).length%20%3D%3D%3D%201%20%26%26%20typeof%20value.x%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20TypeB%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20isTypeB(value%3A%20any)%3A%20value%20is%20TypeB%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(value).length%20%3D%3D%3D%201%20%26%26%20typeof%20value.y%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22number%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20doSomething(typeA%3A%20TypeA)%3B%0Afunction%20doSomething(typeB%3A%20TypeB)%3B%0Afunction%20doSomething(type%3A%20TypeA%20%7C%20TypeB)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isTypeA(type))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(type.x)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(type.y)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

In your example, as the passed value can be only of `TypeA` and `TypeB` then there's no need for the extra if/else.
But you can also use the `isTypeB`.

This method is good if you need this check in a few places in your code, but if you need it for just that one function, then I think that I would go with two different functions, depending on the amount of duplicated code.

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot! My bad, I was too lazy to read everything in the Typescript Handbook, therefore I skipped the user defined type guards..

Comment: Just one more question. It looks that unless the type is an interface, I can use `instanceof` to check the type, right? I don't have to create own type guards

Comment: Yes, `instanceof` and `typeof` are "type guards", while having your own functions is "user defined type guards". I assumed that you have interfaces, my bad.

Comment: No problem, you helped me a lot :).